# How to replace number with symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fix this code below to replace "<3" and "< / 3" (without spaces) without removing "/g":

```
$('#seem').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\<\3/g,"heart"))
  });

$('#seem').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\<\/\3/g,"broken-heart"))
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is and what you expect from it?

Comment: I'm adding emotions to posts, so i want to replace: "<3" to an image of heart in html and "</3" to an image of broken heart.
Note: I didn't add "<img" tag in question, to make it easier.
I just want know how to replace symbol: "<" with number "3"

Comment: Please try providing example for the input and the output of the replacing function you're trying to implement.

Comment: @code2be 
https://ibb.co/jzycCn5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before addressing the problem with text replacement there's a couple of other issues.

Firstly calling `each()` on an id selector is a code smell. Ids need to be unique within the DOM, so there should never be multiple of them. If this is the case, use a class.

Secondly you can provide a function to `html()` or `text()` which accepts the current value as an argument. This cuts down the number of jQuery objects you need to create and makes the logic more succinct.

Next, the `<` in the HTML has to be encoded as `&lt;`, so if you want to use `html()` you'll need to replace that instead of `<` explicitly. Alternatively you can use `text()`, which is decoded, and work with the angle bracket as-is.

Also your Regex isn't quite right as neither the `<` nor the `3` characters need to be escaped, only the `/`.

Finally you can chain calls to `replace()`; you don't need to duplicate the entire jQuery object or `each()` loop in order to replace multiple values in a string.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('.seem').text(function(i, t) {
  return t.replace(/<3/g, 'heart').replace(/<\/3/g, 'broken-heart');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seem">
  Achy breaky &lt;3
</div>
<div class="seem">
  Owner of a &lt;/3
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I used this code below in JS and it worked:

Comment: .replace(/\&lt;3/g,

Comment: Yep, that'll work if you want to stick with `html()`. Glad it solved the issue for you

Comment: and again Thank you.